# jQuery If div has anchor child then

Tags: jquery, html, if-statement, anchor

Having trouble on a simple one. My morning tea isn't strong enough.

IF div has a child that's an anchor THEN- blah. Don't want to add an additional class to .box

Something like:

```
$('.box').click(function(){
    if ($(this).children('a')) {
        //some thing
    } else {
        //some thing else
    }
});

<div class="box"><a href="#"><img src="#" /></a></div>
<div class="box"><img src="#" /></div>
<div class="box"><img src="#" /></div>
```

Comment: If you want `some thing` to be css that is added to the anchor, consider using the css child selector "blam>hoot" which identifies hoot when it is a child of blam.  More concreete "div.box>a"  anchor child of div with class of ".box"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property:

```
$('.box').click(function(){
    if ($(this).children('a').length) {
        //some thing
    } else {
        //some thing else
    }
});
```

Since the `children` method (like most jQuery methods) returns an instance of jQuery, it will always evaluate to `true` (so you'll always end up in the `if` branch). The `length` property returns a number, which will evaluate to `false` if it's `0`.

Comment: bingo bango, that was quick. why is it that i have to measure the amount of anchors? otherwise it returns an array starting at 0 or something?

Comment: The `children` method returns an instance of jQuery which will always evaluate to `true`, whether it contains any elements or not.

Comment: beat me to that, too thanks for the explanation. will accept asap

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find()` to search the selector for additional selectors: http://jsfiddle.net/Nf3QH/  hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

No need for jQuery nowadays you just need to add a bit of vanilla JavaScript, notice that the code is pretty short.

```js
  cells = document.querySelectorAll('div');
          [].forEach.call(cells, function (el) {
          //console.log(el.nodeName)
            if (el.hasChildNodes() && el.firstChild.nodeName=="A") {
            console.log(el)};
        });
```

```html
<div class="box"><a href="#"><img src="#" /></a></div>
<div class="box"><img src="#" /></div>
<div class="box"><img src="#" /></div>
```